# jplayer timeFormat.showHour is not working

Tags: jquery, jplayer

i have implemented the jplayer plugin.
It works, except the showHour Setting.
It only displays the minutes and seconds ...

What is wrong with my code?

```
$("#jplayer-{{ $stream->id }}").jPlayer({
        swfPath: "{{ URL::base().'/javascripts/vendor/' }}",
        supplied: "oga, m4a, mp3",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp-container-{{ $stream->id }}",
        wmode: "window",
        timeFormat: {
            showHour  : true,
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

take out the comma after 'true'